# I want to add the placeholder attribute to the input within this DIV but it does not have a unique property that I could locate it with

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I cannot edit the HTML directly because Squarespace does not allow that, only JS and Jquery can be used.

```
$("#field city :input").attr('placeholder', 'City');
```

I tried using this but it doesn't work

```
<div class="field city">
                <label class="caption"><input class="field-element field-control" name="" x-autocompletetype="" type="text" spellcheck="false" data title="">
                </label>
              </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: with the html you provided, you probably want: $(".field.city input").attr('placeholder', 'City');

Comment: It's because you nested city from #field and #field doesn't have div called city, plus field is an class not an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is not correct for the html provided.

This works:

```
$(".field.city .field-element").attr('placeholder', 'City')
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vx9expf6/)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9j6s1eow/)..

```
<div class="field city">
  <label class="caption"><input class="field-element field-control" name="" x-autocompletetype="" type="text" spellcheck="false" data title="">
  </label>
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName('field-element')[0].placeholder='city'
</script>
```